# Обновление записей в аксес

Tags: база-данных, access

Подскажите, как через запрос можно изменить записи вот так: "мужской" на "мужчина", "женский" на "женщина" одним запросом.
Пробовал в условие отбора ставить первое значение, а в строку Обновление второе, но это не работает + можно менять только 1 значение в запросе, а нужно и мужской, и женский.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE [таблица]
SET [поле] = IIF([поле]="мужской","мужчина","женщина")
WHERE [поле] = "мужской" 
   OR [поле] = "женский"
```

В построителе запросов:

1. Добавить таблицу в верхней части
2. Установить тип запроса - Обновление
3. Заполнить сверху вниз в нижней части в одном столбце:

   - Поле: имя поля
   - Имя таблицы: имя таблицы
   - Обновление: IIf([таблица]![поле]="мужской";"мужчина";"женщина")
   - Условие отбора: "мужской"
   - или: "женский"